# How to count the number of separate regions in python array

Tags: python

I need to count the number of separate regions in an array.

An example array is below. I can count the number of unique strings but if there are two distinct islands like in the grid below where 64733 is in the upper left and bottom right my function won't properly count the number of regions. 
Can anyone help me to find a way to count the number of regions if two of the regions are comprised of the same numbers? Im writing in python 2.x.

```
|64733|20996|92360|92360|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|98101
|64733|92360|92360|92360|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478
|64733|92360|29136|92360|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478
|64733|92360|29136|92360|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478
|92360|92360|92360|92360|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478
|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478
|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478
|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478
|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|64773
|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|04478|64773|64773
```

The input is a 3d array and looks like

```
[[['6', '4', '7', '3', '3'],
  ['2', '0', '9', '9', '6'],
  ['9', '2', '3', '6', '0'],
  ['9', '2', '3', '6', '0'],
  ['0', '4', '4', '7', '8'],
  ['0', '4', '4', '7', '8'],
  ['0', '4', '4', '7', '8'],
  ['0', '4', '4', '7', '8'],
  ['0', '4', '4', '7', '8'],
  ['9', '8', '1', '0', '1']],
 [['6', '4', '7', '3', '3'],
  ['9', '2', '3', '6', '0'],
  ['9', '2', '3', '6', '0'],
  ['9', '2', '3', '6', '0'],
  ['0', '4', '4', '7', '8'],
  ['0', '4', '4', '7', '8'],
  ['0', '4', '4', '7', '8'],
  ['0', '4', '4', '7', '8'],
  ['0', '4', '4', '7', '8'],
  ['0', '4', '4', '7', '8']],
 [['6', '4', '7', '3', '3'],
  ['9', '2', '3', '6', '0'],
```

This is not the complete input (because it was huge) but it gets the point across i think

So would be where any unique symbol string of numbers lies and the total number of adjacent strings that are identical (adjacent being up down left right, not diagonal).

```
enter code here
```

Comment: That is not an array. What is your actual input? What does your code look like? What is a *"region"*?

Comment: Your question is clear, but you need to include your input and output format. Please include those so we can help!

Comment: Can we assume your array is a 2 dimensional NxM array?  This is a common problem in image recognition, wikipedia might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling

Comment: I updated the question to include the input @zvone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post your full array, so I made some assumptions about the original pip separated value you gave us.  I've written this in Python 3, but I think it should work in Python 2 only modifying the print function calls to statements.

```
arr = [["64733","20996","92360","92360","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","98101"],
["64733","92360","92360","92360","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478"],
["64733","92360","29136","92360","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478"],
["64733","92360","29136","92360","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478"],
["92360","92360","92360","92360","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478"],
["04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478"],
["04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478"],
["04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478"],
["04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","64773"],
["04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","04478","64773","64773"]]

x = len(arr)
y = len(arr[0])

#create a new array the same size as the original
regions = [[None for _ in range(y)] for _ in range(x)]

print(regions)

label = 0
queue = []

def check_neighbor(i, j, v):
    if not regions[i][j] and arr[i][j] == v:
        regions[i][j] = label
        queue.insert(0, (i, j))

for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        #don't check an already labelled region
        if regions[i][j]: continue
        label += 1 #new label
        regions[i][j] = label
        queue = [(i, j)]
        v = arr[i][j]
        #keep checking neighbours until we run out
        while queue:
            (X, Y) = queue.pop()
            if X > 0:
                check_neighbor(X-1, Y, v)
            if X < x-1:
                check_neighbor(X+1, Y, v)
            if Y > 0:
                check_neighbor(X, Y-1, v)
            if Y < y-1:
                check_neighbor(X, Y+1, v)

print(regions)
print(label) # this is the number of regions
```